# How to configure a site so that I can have a url without directory the way Wordpress did?

Tags: url, directory

Say I made a website with Wordpress, and created a few pages say www.foo.com/bar1 and www.foo.com/bar2. I have no idea where they stored this, since there is no /bar1 and /bar2 directory. Unlike when I created a site from scratch and added new directories like /public_html/bar1.

So how do I configure it like this without Wordpress?

Comment: Wordpress stores the posts/pages in the DB and serves that dynamically. So you don't see actual mapping files

Comment: I'm not even sure what the question is exactly. Is it about you wanting to create a website with directories like `example.com/page1`? You just make subfolders in your root project and put `index.html` files into each one of them. No framework needed, it's a core capability of any server you will use (Apache or nginx most likely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a page using WordPress, your all page will have a dynamic content with same layout from ***page.php*** file which is a mandatory file of a theme and served according to the routes. You will not see the ***page.php*** in URL or page. WordPress saves your page title in database and servers it accordingly (check the **permalink** section of WordPress).

When you create a custom site from scratch you can do the same by creating a file and re-use it according to the routes. You don't need directory for that.

> **Note:** File extensions like `.php .html` are removed using `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the technology\framework you're using. Google 'Routing'.

Example for Asp.Net: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: This is the key part: in web development, **routing** is the process where the server parses a URL (e.g., `/foo1`) and serves up a specific file, page, or any other valid response. As suggested above, googling "routing" should yield some more results. An example might be - https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/web-development-with/9781491902288/ch14.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a framework like ZK framework to create a div content and refresh it according to the request. This way, you may not have to update any url in your application. You just refresh an inner div by dynamicaly including a new view.

Maybe this would help:

https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Essential_Components/Include